Shopware 6.6 Theme Migration error on build-storefront
I am currently migrating our theme to 6.6(.0.1). The Javascript has already been moved:
=> app/storefront/dist/storefront/js/areanet-standardtheme64/areanet-standardtheme64.js
The theme.json has been adapted accordingly:
 "script": [
    "@Storefront",
    "app/storefront/dist/storefront/js/areanet-standardtheme64/areanet-standardtheme64.js"
  ],

However, when I call build-storefront or theme:compile, the following error message appears and the file is not copied to the corresponding public folder and is therefore not loaded in the frontend:
15:39:18 ERROR     [app] The "custom/apps/AreanetStandardTheme64/AreanetStandardtheme64/Resources/app/storefront/dist/storefront/js/areanet-standardtheme64" directory does not exist.

Try to change your path to
/app/storefront/dist/storefront/js/areanet-standardtheme64/areanet-standardtheme64.js

or
/app/storefront/dist/storefront/js/areanet-standardtheme64.js

